# Comparing each element of multiple dynamics arrays

Tags: java

I have a List of some typed object, where each node of the list has an array[n].

Now, leaving out the time complexity, for now I need to compare each element of the array with all the elements of others arrays inside the list. How can I do that? Because if list was fixed size, I would do something like that (suppose the size is 3):

```
for(Array firstArray : lst.get(0).getArray()){
   for(Array secondArray : lst.get(1).getArray()){
      for(Array thirdArray : lst.get(2).getArray()){
   //do something
                }
           }
   }
```

But with a list with no fixed size? How can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In indeterminate number of loops? Sounds like recursion:

```
void doAll(List<ArrayHolder> lst) {
    doAllFrom(lst, 0);
}
void doAllFrom(List<ArrayHolder> lst, int off) {
    if (off == lst.length()) {
        //do something
    } else {
        ArrayHolder arrayHolder = lst.get(off);
        for (Array nthArray : arrayHolder.getArray()) {
            doAllFrom(lst, off+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you are going to need to do something with `nthArray`. Perhaps adding it to a linear list of current `Array`s:

```
void doAll(List<ArrayHolder> lst) {
    doAllFrom(lst, new ArrayHolder[lst.size()], 0);
}
void doAllFrom(List<ArrayHolder> lst, ArrayHolder[] holders, int off) {
    if (off == lst.size()) {
        //do something
    } else {
        ArrayHolder arrayHolder = lst.get(off);
        for (Array nthArray : arrayHolder.getArray()) {
            holders[off] = nthArray;
            doAllFrom(lst, holders, off+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct, but I think that my question is too generic, sorry for that. The list is n size and the arrays are m size (indipendently from each other). And I have to find elements of each array with a timestamp proximity of 10 seconds. Maybe I will open another question but for now, it's the best answer

Comment: @Pikappa It doesn't matter that the arrays are different sizes - the `for` loop will handle that (one per frame). All the indexes in the code above are in to the list (and matching `ArrayHolder[]`), not your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Array first : lst.get(0).getArray()){
    for(int i: first){                    //i is first element of comparison
       for(Array second : lst.get(0).getArray()){
          for(int j: second){             //j is second element of comparison
              if(i compare j)
              //do something
          }
       }
    }
}
```

this will do your job but complexity is too bad.
Considering elements of arrays are integers.